# angular load template from url and compile inside div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As I'm new to Angular JS I was wondering how could I load an external template and compile it with some data into the targeted `div`.

For instance I have this template :

```
<script type="text/ng-template">

    <img src="{{Thumb}}" />

<script>
```

The `div` that is supposed to contain the template :

```
<div data-ng-controller=" ... "></div>
```

The template is located somewhere in a folder `/templates/test.php`. Is there a build in way of doing the template loading like a directive would do and compile it against some data that would replace the key `{{Thumb}}` ( and many others of course ) ?

**EDIT :** What if I use `$routes` and load a template when I'm in the root of the website ? How could that be achieved ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

in Angular there's 2 ways of using template (at least 2 ways that i know about):

- the first using an inline template (in the same file) with this syntax:

  ```
  <script type="text/ng-template">
      <img ng-src="{{thumb}}">
  </script>
  ```
- the second one (what you want) is external template:

  ```
  <img ng-src="{{thumb}}">
  ```

so what you need to do is to remove the script part from your template and then use the ng-include in the wanted div like this:

`<div ng-include="'templates/test.php'"></div>`

need to have double quotes and single quotes to work.
Hope this helps.

Comment: It seems to be working. The `{{Thumb}}` will be only replaced with a value if I define an controller and I set the `$scope.Thumb` to a value. Also, I get a `404` for the `{{Thumb}}` image source, can that be avoided ?

Comment: put an example on [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:3510140), so I can understand you better.

Comment: Well, take a look at the example they have : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngView ; I'm setting up the same thing right now, but I get redirected, probably because the route doesn't match the location I have ? I have it as `$routeProvider.when('', {
   templateUrl : 'templates/vcard.php',
   controller : "VCardController"
  });`

Comment: Please, set an example code on [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:3510140), here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HLO4zd) about the $routes thing look at line 30 on the app.js file.

Comment: It wouldn't make a difference since what I have it's structured in another way. What I'm trying to say is that the `$routeProvider` when checks the location on page load, it redirects me, because that's what I set it to when none of the locations before aren't matched. But my question is, since the check `$routeProvider.when('/', ...` , shouldn't that be the root folder where my index file is ? Why does it ignore it and redirects ?

Comment: For images you should use ngSrc: `<img ng-src='Thumb'>`

Answer (score 26):

Using [`$templateRequest`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateRequest), you can load a template by it’s URL without having to embed it into your HTML page. If the template is already loaded, it will be taken from the cache.

```js
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $templateRequest, $sce, $compile){
    // Make sure that no bad URLs are fetched. If you have a static string like in this
    // example, you might as well omit the $sce call.
    var templateUrl = $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl('nameOfTemplate.html');

    $templateRequest(templateUrl).then(function(template) {
        // template is the HTML template as a string

        // Let's put it into an HTML element and parse any directives and expressions
        // in the code. (Note: This is just an example, modifying the DOM from within
        // a controller is considered bad style.)
        $compile($("#my-element").html(template).contents())($scope);
    }, function() {
        // An error has occurred here
    });
});
```

Be aware that this is the manual way to do it, and whereas in most cases the preferable way would be to [define](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api) a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) that fetches the template using the `templateUrl` property.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say I have this index.html:

```
 <!doctype html> <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
        <body>
            <script src="tpl/ng.menu.tpl" type="text/ng-template"></script>   
            <mainmenu></mainmenu>       
            <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
        </body> 
</html>
```

---

And I have a template file "tpl/ng.menu.tpl" with only these 4 lines:

```
<ul class="menu"> 
    <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

My directives mapping "js/directives.js":

```
angular.module('myApp',['myApp.directives']);
var myModule = angular.module('myApp.directives', []);

myModule.directive('mainmenu', function() {
    return { 
        restrict:'E',
        replace:true,
        templateUrl:'tpl/ng.menu.tpl'
    }
});
```

Comment: Any idea why Angular sees only the content inside the `<script>` tags and not its loaded file content specified with the `src` attribute?